# Transversality Condition and the Proof of Smale Theorem (Audin-Damian), Lemma 2.2.8 (Part 2)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields, morse-theory, transversality

In Audin and Damian, p.44-45, there seems to be a claim that one can prove transversality without directly showing the tangent spaces span the tangent space of the ambient manifold. In particular, in the following [image]

the last sentence seems to claim that if two manifolds intersect in a submanifold, and the codimension of the intersection in the first equals the codimension of the second in the ambient manifold then they are transverse.

This would contradict a line tangent to a parabola in the plane, however. Would someone understand how transversality is implied here?

Comment: Aren’t you forgetting the hypothesis that $w$ is a regular value of $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue now. Let me call the submanifolds of $V^n$ by $W^{n-k}$ and $P^{n-l}$. Fix a point in $p$ in $W\cap P$.

The condition $codim_P W^{n-k}\cap P^{n-l} = codim_V W^{n-k}$ implies that $W^{n-k}\cap P^{n-l}$ has dimension $n-k-l$.

In particular, the largest linearly independent set in $T_p(W\cap P)$ is of size $n-k-l$, say $$v_1,...,v_{n-k-l}.$$
Since $T_p W$ has dimension $n-k$, we may choose $l$ more linearly independent tangent vectors  $$u_{n-k-l+1},...,u_{n-k}$$ which complete a basis in $T_pW$, but none of these lie in $T_p (W\cap P)$.

There are also $k$ tangent vectors $$w_{n-k+1},...,w_n$$ in $T_pP$ which complete a basis for $T_pP$ with the $v_i$.

**Claim:** These $v_i$'s, $u_i$'s, and $w_i$'s together form a basis for $T_pV$, and we can do this at every point, showing transversality.$\square$

*Justification:* In fact, we can start with the linearly independent set $v_1,...,v_{n-k-l},u_{n-k-l+1},...,u_{n-k}$ in $T_pV$, and start filling it with the $w_i$.

If some $w_j$ is a linear combination of the previous ones, such linear combination can be chosen not to include the previous $w$'s (say, by subtracting whatever contributions they had first, and keeping the label $w_j$ for it). Then looking at the tangent space as the space of germs of curves at $p$, $$w_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k-l} \lambda_iv_i + \sum_{i=n-k-l+1}^{n-k} \mu_iu_i \Rightarrow w_j - \sum_{i=1}^{n-k-l} \lambda_iv_i = \sum_{i=n-k-l+1}^{n-k} \mu_iu_i.$$

The LHS says there's a regular curve centered at $p$ in $P$ that generates it.
The RHS says there's a regular curve centered at $p$ in $W$ that generates it.

This means both curves agree on a small neighborhood $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. This means this piece of curve (the restrictions of both to $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$) lie in both $W$ and $P$, and hence the underlying tangent vector must be a linear combination of the $v_i$'s, say $\sum\nu_iv_i$.

Then $w_j$ becomes $\sum \nu_iv_i + \sum \lambda_iv_i$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $W^s_{X'} \cap P$ is a codimension $k$ submanifold of $P$ follows from the regular value theorem. The tranversality follows from Grassmann's formula. If $x \in W^s_{X'} \cap P$, then we have
$$ \dim (T_x W^s_{X'} + T_x P) = \dim (T_x W^s_{X'}) + \dim (T_xP) - \dim \big(T_x (W^s_{X'} \cap P) \big) = n - k + k = n. $$